# Comparing Time Series with Different Sample Times Using Linear Interpolation in Pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series

***Background:***
I have experimental data taken over the course of one month. Data values were taken somewhat periodically, but did not divide evenly into a full day. Thus the measurements start on day one at midnight, but start on day one at 00:03, and day two at 00:07, etc. So the data readings taken each day are shifted. In addition there is a slight variation in the frequency between readings. The experimental conditions on the first three days were repeated the last three days to compare the effects of the intermediate days.

***Goal:*** I would like to compare the repeated days to each other, taking a difference between them.

***Problem:*** The 1st day and 25th day should be compared, but the relative daily times do not correspond, so I would like to compare the linear interpolation of the first day to the data points of the 25th day. i.e. For each timedelta (relative to the start of the day) on the 25th day, I would like to subtract the same point from the first day. If there is no corresponding point on the first day, I would like to use the linear interpolation between the nearest points.

***So Far:***
I have the Pandas Dataframes indexed by row, with columns *time* and *value*, both are Floats. I created a new column *delta* using `pandas.to_timedelta()` on the *time* column. I have tried subtracting the 1st and 25th day but because the indices do not align I end up with many NaN values. I also tried making *delta* the index, but still couldn't figure out how to get the calculation correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by

1. Setting the index of both DataFrame's to the dependent variable `data.set_index( day_time )`
2. Creating a union of the two DataFrame's indices `combined_index = df1.index.union( df2.index )`
3. Reindexing both DataFrame's with the combined index `df = df.reindex( combined_index )`
4. Interpolating the DataFrames `df = df.interpolate( how = 'linear' )`

This created a mutual set of indices in both DataFrames allowing easy comparison using the arithmetic operators.

Comment: Thanks. I recommend using [`.interpolate( method = 'time' )`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html), so that the timestamp index can be used to return the y-value at the correct point on the line.